# Objective-c / Is it possible to encrypt rsa using modulus and exponent without external library?

Tags: objective-c, public-key-encryption, modulo, exponent

Today, I implemented rsa encryption logic using openssl. Is it possible without an external library like openssl? Using a public key made of modulus and exponent.

My source is roughly like this.

```
-(NSString *)hexWithData:(unsigned char *)data ofLength:(NSUInteger)len
{
    NSMutableString *tmp = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        [tmp appendFormat:@"%02x", data[i]];
    }
    
    return tmp;
}

-(void)EncryptionWithRSA
{
    RSAGenWithSecurity *akClass = [[RSAGenWithSecurity alloc] init];
    NSString *plainText = [akClass ParseJWT];
    const char *plain = [plainText UTF8String];
    
    RSA *publickey = [self GenKeyWithRSA];
    
    int rsa_length = RSA_size(publickey);
    unsigned char *crip[rsa_length];
    
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] init];
    
    int iRsaRet = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(plain), (const unsigned char *)plain, (unsigned char *)crip, publickey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    
    if(iRsaRet <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"encrypt failed");
        result = @"";
    } else {
        result = [self hexWithData:crip ofLength:rsa_length];
//        result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)crip];
        
        NSLog(@"encrypt success: %@", result);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry to ask you an immature question through a translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible. To implement you'd have the following.

1. A stream of bytes you need to encrypt.
2. The RSA modulus and exponent. Suppose the modulus is `n` bytes long.

Now to encrypt the stream you'd do it as follows.

1. Use a chunk of bytes that is `n` bytes long. If not, pad (postfix) with zero.
2. Raise the chunk to the power of the exponent (e.g. using successive squares) and calculate modulus the modulus.
3. If the result is not `n` bytes long then zero pad again (this time prefix).

That is it, you have an encrypted stream.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I don't know how to implement logic yet. Do you have any examples that I can refer to?

Comment: It is not trivial. I think you have to work it out on paper first and then implement. The padding is the easy bit. If you implement in Objective-C you need some way to represent very large integers. I developed my own lib to do this in low level C for performance, but you could do this using Accelerate's vBigNum.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We should implement logic directly in the way you told us. I also regret that I only tried to solve it too easily.